# Having issues with project files since upgrade

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, flutter

A friend working on `XCode` is having the same issue since we upgraded our `flutter versions last weekend. There is no error message on the console but I do get an error with the .iml main file of the project. I usually take the file out, paste it back and problem solved with the file. But the issue of the image keeps and we can't simulate till its fixed

[image: error]

Comment: what is a proyect, did you mean project ?

Comment: I mean the whole foldier were the work is, where the images, the code files, everything is.